# Weird encoding in ubuntu package configuration

Tags: ubuntu

This is a fresh linode Ubuntu 10.04 LTS vps. I am trying to install postfix, but I get weird character encodings in the package config and cannot choose options. I had the same thing with mysql but ignored it since I could still type in the root password, but here I cannot choose the setting I need.

[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrzQL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal, `echo $TERM` and compare this to the settings that you're using in whatever terminal program you're running.  They should basically match so that the server knows what the capabilities of your terminal program are, and can send the right types of special characters and signals for screen drawing.

If your terminal is emulating, say, xterm, then, when you ssh into the VPS, you should run `export TERM=xterm` (or whatever your terminal program is emulating).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the character set in putty to UTF-8 and it works now!